# Cann't call authenticate method of spring security for login REST service

Tags: spring, rest, spring-security

I want to check username and password in authenticationProvider but dont know why i cann't get call to authenticate method. I am implementing REST login service through spring security. my web.xml is

```
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
        WEB-INF/spring-security.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<!-- Spring Security Filter  -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
    </filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>
            com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages
        </param-name>
        <param-value>com.zymr.ojo.action</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>jsp/login.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

and spring-security.xml is as below...

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.zymr.ojo" />
<security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" secured-     annotations="enabled" />

<!-- Security configuration for REST services. -->
<security:http use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="restEntryPoint" create-  session="always">
    <!-- <security:http-basic/> -->
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/rest/question/**"  access="isAuthenticated()"/>
   <!--  <security:intercept-url pattern="/rest/login/userLogin" access="permitAll"/> -->
   <security:form-login login-processing-url="/rest/login/userLogin" username-parameter="admin" password-parameter="password"/>
</security:http>

<!-- Authentication manager. -->
<security:authentication-manager >
    <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="authProvider" >
        </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>

<!-- Entry point for REST service. -->
<bean id="restEntryPoint" class="com.zymr.ojo.security.RestAuthenticationEntryPoint" />

<!-- A handler for successful REST service authentication. -->
<bean id="authSuccessHandler" class="com.zymr.ojo.security.RestAuthenticationSuccessHandler"></bean>
<bean id="authProvider" class="com.zymr.ojo.security.RestAuthenticationProvider" ></bean>
```

and RESTAuthenticationProvider class is

@Component public class 
    RestAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider,
    UserDetailsService{

```
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication)
        throws AuthenticationException {
    System.out.println("in authProvider");
    String username = authentication.getName();
    String password = (String) authentication.getCredentials();
    if(username != null && password != null){
        System.out.println(username+ "  "+ password);
    }
    return null;
}

public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
        throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    System.out.println(username);
    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: What happens exactly ? Any error message ? Any logs ? Bells ringing all around ? And ... what does `RestAuthenticationEntryPoint` ?

Comment: This is my RestEntryPoint                                                                                                   public final class RestAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
  AuthenticationException auth) throws IOException, ServletException {

 System.out.println("in rest entry point");
 response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED,"Unauthorised");
 }
}

Comment: I can see no custom filter in your config, and your entry point simply returns 403. When should `AuthenticationManager.authenticate()` be called ? Where do you want to pass username and password ?

Comment: I see my problem is authenticate method from authenticateProvider didnt get called ...also i think that authenticate object didnt get request object content so i cannt access request object content in authenticate method(Username and password)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the `supports(..)` method that always returns false. Your entry point should provide the user a way to populate an instance of `Authentication` and this will be given to the `authenticate` method *if* the supports method returns true.

Comment: please pardon me but i dont know which support method you are talking about....All i want is to get request content in authenticate method ...i have googled it but had not yet found any proper solution to my problem ...thanks for writing me pls keep posted...

Comment: @Swapnil1988 The `supports` method of your `AuthenticationProvider` as shown in the code fragment. You need to properly implement it.

Comment: Hi i have changed that suport method and now i get sysout printed from  authenticate get printed but still no data in authenticate object.(No username and password)

Comment: public boolean supports(Class<? extends Object> authentication) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
 }

Answer (score -1):

Please refer to the following link. This link specified adding UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter. I tried this but it is not calling the login.html form.

http://www.networkedassets.com/configuring-spring-security-for-a-restful-web-services/

Comment: While this link may theoretically answer the question it would be better to explain the answer here.

Comment: Yes sir i have been referring this site  from begining.... but come to no solution ...thank you for taking interest ...keep posted.